# how to output every line in a file python

Tags: python, file, input

```
     if data.find('!masters') != -1:
         f = open('masters.txt')
         lines = f.readline()
         for line in lines:
               print lines
               sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + str(lines) + '\r\n')
               f.close()
```

masters.txt has a list of nicknames, how can I print every line from the file at once?. The code I have only prints the first nickname. Your help will be appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Should `f.close()` be outside of the for loop? Also, just `for line in open('masters.txt'):` should do.

Comment: umm that doesn't work, it keeps printing out the first line about 5 times

Comment: That's because your code only reads one line -- only one call to `readline()` is made. `lines` only contains one line (which has a trailing newline on it, BTW). Another problem is that after you `print` and `sck.send()` that single line in `lines` the first time, you close the file so you can't read any more from it if you tried. The `for` however will try to keep executing for each *character* in the line though, `print`ing and `sck.send()`ing that same line over and over until or unless an error occurs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Firstly, as @l33tnerd said, `f.close` should be outside the for loop.

Secondly, you are only calling `readline` once, before the loop. That only reads the first line. The trick is that in Python, files act as iterators, so you can iterate over the file without having to call any methods on it, and that will give you one line per iteration:

```
 if data.find('!masters') != -1:
     f = open('masters.txt')
     for line in f:
           print line,
           sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + line)
     f.close()
```

Finally, you were referring to the variable `lines` inside the loop; I assume you meant to refer to `line`.

Edit: Oh and you need to indent the contents of the `if` statement.

Comment: Also `print line` should have a comma at the end to avoid double-spacing.

Comment: For the same reason, the `sck.send()` probably doesn't need a `'\r\n'` at the end.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot to even look at what `sck.send` was doing. It doesn't really need the `str` either. So it should just be `sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + line)`, or better still, `sck.send("PRIVMSG %d %s" % (chan, line))`.

Comment: Or alternatively, `sck.send("PRIVMSG {0} {1}".format(chan, line))`. Regardless of which form you prefer, I suggest that you update your answer.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want something like:

```
if data.find('!masters') != -1:
     f = open('masters.txt')
     lines = f.read().splitlines()
     f.close()
     for line in lines:
         print line
         sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + str(line) + '\r\n')
```

Don't close it every iteration of the loop and print line instead of lines.  Also use readlines to get all the lines.

**EDIT** removed my other answer - the other one in this discussion is a better alternative than what I had, so there's no reason to copy it.

Also stripped off the \n with read().splitlines()

Comment: That will work, but my solution is (usually) better as it won't read the entire file into memory first; it will process each line as it reads it in from the file. The disadvantage of mine is that you can't close the file until you're done.

Comment: @mgiuca - poster never mentioned anything about the size of the file.  The memory won't be an issue if the file is small, which I am assuming  a list of nicknames will be.

Comment: Yeah, I just generally think it's good practice not to use O(N) memory if you can get away with using O(1) without too much trouble.

Comment: It looks like the code in your answer (and the OP's) isn't taking into account the fact that both `readline()` and `readlines()` both retain the trailing newline characters in the line(s) they return. The result will be lots of blank lines being printed and sent.

Comment: @SB: That while loop and the two calls to f.readline make your code look distressingly like Pascal. Just use `for line in f`

Comment: FWIW, `for line in f` also preserves the trailing newline characters.

Answer (score 6):

You could try this.  It doesn't read all of f into memory at once (using the file object's iterator) and it closes the file when the code leaves the with block.

```
if data.find('!masters') != -1:
    with open('masters.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
            sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + line + '\r\n')
```

If you're using an older version of python (pre 2.6) you'll have to have

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Answer (score 5):

Loop through the file.

```
f = open("masters.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
for line in open("masters", "r").readlines(): print line
```

?

```
readline()
```

only reads "a line", on the other hand

```
readlines()
```

reads whole lines and gives you a list of all lines.

Comment: More importantly `readlines()` reads the entire file into memory with each line will and its trailing newline intact, so the `print line` will output two of them. The `for line in open()` text file reading coding style also leaves the file open after the loop finishes since there's no way to refer to it again and `close()` it.