# Python prints only first line of textfile

Tags: python

I have a textfile with a few lines and want to print them, but it only prints the first line. And if I use a loop (see code below) it prints the first line vertically..

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
file.close()
for line in data:
     print (line)
```

Comment: you ar closing the file bevor you read all lines

Comment: `data` is a string, not a list of lines.

Comment: @Patrick85 ok i'm an idiot, but it stills print the first line vertical :D

Comment: You probably meant `file.readlines()`. Also, avoid using `file` as a variable name.

Comment: Operating system and python version? Also try using 'rb' if you're on windows. Omg, data is a string, not list of strings... use for line in data.splitlines():

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to output every line in a file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709655/how-to-output-every-line-in-a-file-python)

Answer (score 4):

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
data = file.readlines()
for line in data:
     print (line)
file.close()
```

Comment: This method is too long take a big file of several MB you read whole file instead to read only first lines

Comment: @glegoux: the instructions are:  _I have a textfile with a few lines and want to print them_

Comment: Read the title `Python prints only first line of textfile`

Comment: I think you've misread `I have a textfile with a few lines and want to print them, but it only prints the first line` the problem is that it only prints the first line, he does not want to print only the first line

Answer (score 4):

Try using `with` to automactially close your file and keep your code a little more readable/pythonic :

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print (line)
```

Comment: This method is too long take a big file of several MB you read whole file instead to read only first lines

Comment: I believe OP wants to read the whole file, as the file he has contains only a few lines technically he only needs to read a few lines but the question seems to mean the entire file needs to be read

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement to read a text file is generally a good idea.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
  data = file.read()
```

To read only the **first line**, use [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?file.readline#file.readline) it's made for this (using [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) like other answers suggests is not efficient):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
  first_line = file.readline()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in open('file.txt', 'r'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Note that the variable `line` in this solution contains the line separator

Answer (score -1):

**file.txt**:

```
1 foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz
2 foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo bizz bizz bizz bizz foo foo
3 foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo bizz bizz bizz bizz foo foo
4 foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz
5 foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo bizz bizz bizz bizz foo foo
6 foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz
```

Do:

```
def print_first_lines(filename, n):
    with open(filename, 'r') as desc:
        for _ in range(n):
            print(desc.readline().strip())

print_first_lines('file.txt', 1)
```

Output:

```
1 foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz foo buzz bizz
```