# Printing lines in file without resetting the pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, printing, pycharm

I'm learning Python, and right now I want to print specific lines in a file, in this instance all even numbered lines (assuming base 1).

In countless place on the internet, I see the same simple loop which allegedly works. E.g. [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709655/how-to-output-every-line-in-a-file-python), or [this article](https://cmdlinetips.com/2011/08/three-ways-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-python/).

They all use the method below

```
f = open('output.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

For me, this returns nothing at all, except for *"Process finished with exit code 0"*

Using `f.seek(0)` before `for line...` confirmed my suspicion that the pointer was at the bottom of the file.

With this information, I constructed the following

```
f = open('Output.txt', 'r')
startline = 1
s = (startline-1 | 1) + 1 #determine first even line nr. from specified starting line
count = 0

for a in f: count += 1

for line in range(s-1, count, 2):
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.readlines()[line])
```

This works, but it does not explain why it seems to be so common for people *not* to reset the pointer to the top.

Next to that, this prints all necessary lines but with a blank line in between. If I use `print(f.readlines()[line] + 'END')` instead, the results are as follows, seemingly the blank line is now necessarily a new line?

> Yes, brave Sir Robin turned about
>   END
>   And gallantly he chickened out
>   END
>   Bravely talking to his feet
>   END
>   He beat a very brave retreatEND

Process finished with exit code 0

**EDIT:**
my current entire code

```
f = open('Output.txt')
startline = 1
s = (startline-1 | 1) + 1
count = 0

for a in f: count += 1
f.seek(0)
for line in range(s-1, count, 2):
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.readlines()[line], end = '')

for line in f:
    print(line)
```

with output

> Yes, brave Sir Robin turned about
>   And gallantly he chickened out
>   Bravely talking to his feet
>   He beat a very brave retreat
>   Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The blank line you're seeing is because, when you're reading the file, it reads *everything* in the file. Including the newline character (`\n`) at the end of each line. Since the `print()` statement puts a newline after its contents by default, you end up with two newlines instead of just the one you want. There are two ways to fix this: either do `line.strip()` to get rid of the whitespace on either side (including the newline), or add the argument `end=''` to the `print()` call to stop `print()` from doing a newline after whatever it prints

Comment: I'm still perplexed by why the simple for loop wasn't working for you. Are you sure you're opening the file in `r` mode?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: And the file name  is correct? You have `output.txt` and `Output.txt` in places

Comment: @rdas yes. I am looking at my code again and it appears that `for a in f: count += 1` before the simple loop I am finding online is actually setting the pointer at the bottom of the file. You could answer the question and I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe it'll help if you post the full section where you're doing this.

Comment: @rdas added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result without bothering the file pointer:

```
with open('Output.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i%2 == 1:
            print(line, end = '')
```

(Checking for odd numbered lines since you want to start counting from 1)

Comment: That is way more elegant, cheers. Why would I choose `with` instead of `f = open(...`? They both work

Comment: `with` will automatically close your file-descriptor once control leaves the `with` block. Without that, you have to manually call `f.close` or risk leaking the file-descriptor resource.